# What is wrong with the below Null-Conditional Operator?

Tags: c#, nullable, c#-6.0

What is wrong with

```
public int Add(int? a, int? b)
{
    return (a?.0 + b?.0);
}
```

Compile Error: **Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'bool'**

Just trying to get the flavour of adding two nullable integers in the C#6.0 way.

I know the other ways too(like *hasvalue* etc.), but I am experimenting with this new operator.

Comment: The null-conditional operator is `??` (even though it's only `?` for nullable types). `?` is already used for the ternary operator.

Comment: please see this new operator https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx

Comment: The error message is interesting... Why is it trying to convert the value to `bool`?

Comment: Correct implementation of this method would have been `return a ?? 0 + b ?? 0`.

Comment: @DarrenYoung Thanks for putting nomenclature straight. I still like to think of it as a conditional. In any case it's still wrong in the question's code fragment ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, first of all `x?.0` doesn't mean anything when `x` is an `int?`. `0` isn't a property or method on `int?`.

It seems as though you were trying to use the null coalescing operator `??` instead of the null conditional operation `?.`. If that's the case your method should look like this:

```
public int Add(int? a, int? b)
{
    return a ?? 0 + b ?? 0;
}
```

If that's not the case and you meant `?.` then you can test this operator with an extension method to `int` that just returns its value:

```
public static int Identity(this int value)
{
    return value;
}
```

And use it as you tried to originally (but with `int?`):

```
public int? Add(int? a, int? b)
{
    return a?.Identity() + b?.Identity();
}
```

However, if you just want to combine these `int?` parameters together you don't need anything new. This just works:

```
public int? Add(int? a, int? b)
{
    return (a + b);
}
```

Both options will return a result when both parameters aren't `null`, otherwise it would return `null`.

Comment: Ok... More interesting question... Why the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'bool'`? Shouldn't it be `int doesn't contain a definition for `0` or something similar?

Comment: The result of this second Add is probably different... `null + null` == `null`, and `x + null == null` for every `x`, while his method was `null + 5 == 5`

Comment: @xanatos why would you think it would have returned `null + 5 == 5`?

Comment: I think he meant with `a?.0` something like `a ?? 0`, so `null + 5 == 0 + 5`

Comment: Because `.0` is a floating point literal, and so it treats `?` as a token, not `?.`.

Comment: @xanatos The compiler thinks this expression is using the ternary operator twice. It's looking for `bool ? bool ? value : value : value`

Comment: @PavelMinaev I don't think that's surprising. The question is why it tries to get a `bool` out of it.

Comment: @i3arnon: Because the `?.` is followed by a number and not by a letter. Why? Because `?.` checks the result (property, Methody result) if it's null or not. `0` is invalid name for a property or method.

Comment: Because `?` is the first part of the ternary operator `.. ? .. : ..`, which requires the type of the first operand to be `bool`. Like I said, the point here is that you're not actually using `?.` at all. Rather, the dot is a part of a floating-point literal `.0`, leaving `?` as a token by itself.

Comment: @PavelMinaev Is that for me? Because I've already commented with the same idea...